# Getting a Track from a Spotify ID using the libspotify,dll

Tags: asp.net, spotify, libspotify

I can find tracks using the `libspotify.dll` just fine.

But if I have a Spotify Id like: `7KEYPk9d9hc1rrHVmztrUS`. It does not matter if I set "track:" in front.

Actually I am using a .Net wrapper of the dll but that does not give me any results when I give it the Id.

Comment: I mean getting a track from that Spotify Id. Sorry:-)

Answer (score 0):

Well. By the way LibSpotify is obsolete. But back to your problem:
If you have a look at their 'new' Web API there is a way to use a search feature (you do not need authorization for this)
https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7KEYPk9d9hc1rrHVmztrUS

Related to LibSpotify I just found an example
https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/search_8c-example.html